# Bundler on linux doesn't accept rcx versions?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, bundler

During my capistrano deployment, I run into this error

```
Bundler could not find compatible versions for gem "nokogiri":
  In snapshot (Gemfile.lock):
    nokogiri (= 1.6.8.rc3)

  In Gemfile:
    nokogiri (>= 1.6.8.rc3) x64-mingw32

    nokogiri (>= 1.6.8.rc3)

    rails-dom-testing x64-mingw32 was resolved to 1.0.7, which depends on
      nokogiri (~> 1.6.0) x64-mingw32

    rails-dom-testing x64-mingw32 was resolved to 1.0.7, which depends on
      nokogiri (~> 1.6.0)
```

I don't understand, shouldn't `~> 1.6.0` accept my locked version `1.6.8.rc3` ? I am running the Rails app locally perfectly after calling `bundle` (and I'm on Windows, lol), but the deployment fails on a Ubuntu machine.

Is it caused by the `nokogiri (1.6.8.rc3-x64-mingw32)` in the GEM>specs of my Gemfile.lock ? I updated this guy so I could use Ruby 2.3 on Windows, but I have to sacrifice Linux for that ?

Answer (score 0):

In your `Gemfile.lock`, just remove any lines and tree branches with `mingw32`. For example, if your `gemfile.lock` contains the lines:

```
nokogiri (1.6.6.2)
  mini_portile (~> 0.6.0)
nokogiri (1.6.6.2-x86-mingw32)
  mini_portile (~> 0.6.0)
```

Remove the `mingw32` section and it should become like this:

```
nokogiri (1.6.6.2)
  mini_portile (~> 0.6.0)
```

Then the `Gemfile.lock` generated on Windows should work for Ubuntu.

You may want always to commit the `Gemfile.lock` with no occurrences of `mingw32`.

Alternatively just remove the `Gemfile.lock` and execute `bundle install` directly on the Ubuntu machine.

Comment: It was so painful that I gave up. Of course if I delete the lines with `mingw32`, the gemfile becomes corrupted because of a missing dependency. running bundle would regenerate the file identically. On linux, it seems to complain the gem doesn't even exist (I believe this rcx is a Windows-only version).

I will stick to Ruby 2.2 on Windows and bump up to 2.3 when libraries finally accomodate Ruby 2.3 on Windows.